# JAVA Quartz's puzzle

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scrapy

My Project is to build up a schedule system to schedule some crawler at a specific time by cron expression, and i choose to use quartz. I create a sub process in a Job object. When the job is scheduled, it'll created a process to launch a scrapy crawler to fetch the data, and the father process is wait using `waitFor() java api.` Sth like this:

```
 public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
                JobKey jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
                System.out.println("CrawlerJob says: " + jobKey + " executing at " + new Date());
                JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
                String scrapycmd=dataMap.getString("ScrapyCMD");
                Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scrapycmd);

                System.out.println("wait for process...");
                process.waitFor();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            _log.info(e.toString());
        }
}
```

the ScrapyCMD is `scrapy crawl myspider`. however, when it scheduled, i found the process was only work in a very shortime, and then i was using `ps -aux | grep python`:

```
gabriel   4202  0.0  1.0 755672 39400 pts/2    Sl+  22:14   0:02 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl myspider
```

the status of the subprocess is sl+, and the whole process was halt there. How to fix it and  let the subprocess executed in this Job object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your child process generates some output and then is blocked, as you're not reading this output in your main process. If so, you have two options to resolve the issue:

- Read from child process's output stream explicitly to prevent it from blocking

or

- (Java 7 only) Use ProcessBuilder API to merge streams of a child project with parent's streams:

  ProcessBuilder pb =  new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
   pb.inheritIO();
   Process p = pb.start();

Comment: I was using strace to trace the scrapy process, found that it was sleeped, and it halt on at write system call:write(2, "2013-06-17 21:30:02+0800 [data". it already write something in target file..